# В чем отличие итератора от генераторного выражения?

Tags: python, python-3.x, итераторы, генераторы

Пример:

```
a = iter([i ** 2 for i in range(10000)])
b = (i ** 2 for i in range(10000))
```

В чем существенная разница?

В переменной `a` находится итератор списка, пройдя поэлементно мы получим определенные значения, а в переменной `b` находится генераторное-выражение, пройдясь поэлементно по которому мы получим те же самые значения. Так в чем же отличие?

Comment: в том, что генератор не занимает память на все элементы, а выдает их по одному

Comment: @АлексейР так и итератор то же самое ведь делает, я его не конвертировал в `list`

Comment: Лист уже внутри

Comment: @АлексейР `print(sys.getsizeof(a), sys.getsizeof(b))` выдал `48` и `208`, несущественное различие, если сконвертировать в list, то занимать будет `80056`

Comment: вы все вместе считайте, со списком

Comment: @АлексейР что значит со списком, я пример предоставил, вот переменная `a` и переменная `b` посчитал сколько они занимают в памяти, почти одинаково, причем тут список

Comment: для а считайте размер а+размер списка, для б - только б

Comment: Попробуйте сделать миллиард элементов, и вы очень быстро заметите, что совсем не одинаково. "причем тут список" - при том, что вы создаёте целый список в первом варианте

Comment: @АлексейР так а почему я это должен вручную делать, если список внутри, то питон сам должен его посчитать и добавить в размер

Comment: он добавил ссылку и посчитал размер ссылки на список

Comment: @AnonymousWizard не должен, он считает размер не списка, а ссылки на список

Comment: тогда все понял, спасибо, затупил

Comment: @andreymal то есть итератор не экономит память, раз содержит ссылку на уже готовый объект?

Comment: @AnonymousWizard не экономит, пока готовый объект существует и жрёт собой память

Comment: Однако стоит отметить, что итерирование по списку может быть быстрее, чем итерирование по генераторному выражению (но не стоит забывать, что создание списка тоже занимает время, так что где какой способ будет работать быстрее - вопрос неоднозначный)

Comment: А если написать вот так, то разница практически исчезнет )) `a = iter(i ** 2 for i in range(10000))`

Comment: @CrazyElf ого, а почему так? разные структуры данных будут делать одно и то же?

Comment: @CrazyElf или просто потому, что будет взят итератор от того же генераторного выражения и по сути во втором варианте он неявно сам вызывается и это тоже самое?)

Comment: @AnonymousWizard Ну да, так просто берётся `iter` от того же самого генераторного выражения )  Синтаксис питона позволяет при вызове функции от генераторного выражения не писать двойные круглые скобки. Во втором выражении `iter` явно не вызывается, но если по нему проитерироваться, то кажется он тогда всё-равно вызовется от него, если я ничего не путаю )

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо, понятно)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Итератор - любой объект, которые реализует метод `__iter__`. Генератор - объект который вычисляет значение по мере необходимости, т.е. каждый раз когда его просят. Любой генератор это итератор, но не наоборот.

В вашем примере если заменить `10000` на `10**100`, то первый вариант займёт всю память и полностью остановит программу. Второй пример будет работать нормально, потому что он не будет считать все значения сразу, а только когда понадобится.